# Gradle sync failed, android-studio3.6.3 Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ‘:classpath’

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Gradle sync failed: Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

> org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.71.
>   ..............

I deleted the file C:\Users\Ahmad.gradle\cashes
and the error message changed to this:

> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3. No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3 available for offline mode

I don't want to turn off offline mode because that will make the 1st error message to come back again.

- Android Studio 3.6.3
- Android Gradle Plugin Version 3.6.3
- Gradle Version 5.6.4
- Build Tools Version 28.0.3
- API 28: Android 9 (Pie)

I use Java

Comment: File->invalidate caches/restart

Comment: Nothing changed, still have same Erorrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

To Create a JAVA_HOME environment variable with a valid JDK location & select it from (Project Structure > JDK Location) @ Android Studio:

- Right click My Computer and select Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment 
  Variables > then select Edit the system environment variables
- Click the Environment Variables button.
- Under System Variables, click New.
- In the Variable Name field, enter JAVA_HOME.
- In the Variable Value field, enter your JDK installation path.
  Ex: C:\Program Files\Android\jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25
- Click OK and Apply Changes as prompted.

Also I did turn the Firewall program off so I think its a connection problem maybe.